# How to rewrite my url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hy!

I'm developing a web site and have a small problem with `.htaccess`.

Problem:
how to rewrite urls?

```
From: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=about 
To:   http://www.mysite.com/about/
```

and

```
From: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=stuff&catId=1
To:   http://www.mysite.com/stuff/1/
```

and

```
From: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=stuff&catId=1#someAnchor
To:   http://www.mysite.com/stuff/1/#someAnchor
```

Currently I'm doing this but it doesn't work! :(

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&catId=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance, Silvano.

Comment: Why not just include these in your PHP script? You can just redirect when a specific page is requested..

Comment: Because it's is more friendly for search engines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
#Rewrite /about/ to /index.php?page=about
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

#/stuff/1/ to /index.php?page=stuff&catId=1
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&catId=$2 [NC,L]

#/stuff/1/#someAnchor to /index.php?page=stuff&catId=1#someAnchor   
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/(#[0-9a-z]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&catId=$2$3 [NC,L]
```

Works on my local server (WAMP).

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I have got an "Internal Server Error". Some other ideas? Best regards.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I had some unknown characters in my .htaccss. Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&catId=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Do you have in httpd.conf the following line? LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 0):

What you currently have i your `.htaccess` file is not related to your rewrite requests.

Here is what you need:

The first:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

The second:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]*)$ index.php?page=$1&catId=$2
```

Be sure to add `RewriteEngine on` at the top.

Your server will never get the "#someAnchor" part of the url, because no browser in the world will send this as part of the request. The browser keeps it private.